it says argument 2 missing or nil, can anyone help me?
script.Parent.Play.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Enabled = false

    for i, v in pairs(script.Parent:GetDescendants()) do
        if v:IsA("TextButton") then
            v.Visible = false
        end
    end

    tweenService:Create(script.Parent, tweenInfoPopups, {Position = UDim2.new(0.5,0,1.25,0)}):Play()
    tweenService:Create(script.Parent.Parent.Title. tweenInfoPopups, {Position = UDim2.new(0.5,0,-1.25,0)}):Play()

    tweenService:Create(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Transition, tweenInfoPopups, {Position = UDim2.new(0,0,.5,0)}):Play()

    wait(1)

    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.CameraScript.Enabled = false
    game.Workspace.Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom

    tweenService:Create(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Transition, tweenInfoPopups, {position = UDim2.new(-1,0,.5,0)}):Play()

    wait(1)
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Destroy()
end)

i was following a tutorial on yt and then when i finished i tried to playtest the game but it says argument 2 missing or nil for this line :
tweenService:Create(script.Parent, tweenInfoPopups, {Position = UDim2.new(0.5,0,1.25,0)}):Play()


what's tweenInfoPopups?

Your missing the TweenInfo argument which is the 2nd argument for the method TweenService:Create() which you are using. You have the variable tweenInfoPopups as the 2nd argument but it seems like you are missing the variable which causes the error you are having.
local tweenInfoPopups: TweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    1, -- Time
    Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, -- EasingStyle
    Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, -- EasingDirection
    0, -- RepeatCount (when less than zero the tween will loop indefinitely)
    false, -- Reverses (tween will reverse once reaching it's goal)
    0 -- DelayTime
)

Above is a variable containing a generic TweenInfo you can use to fix your error by adding it to the top of your script or before the line which causes your error. I've commented out what each parameter so you know what each one does.
